# Change table row color if database field says yes

Tags: mysql, if-statement, background-color

I want to be able to change this color:

```
<td bgcolor="**LightGrey**">row 2, cell 1</td>
```

depending on the value in the database.

#### Example:

If database says:

- taken: the color should be blue
- reserved: the color should be lightgrey

I know how to connect to the database and everything, it would be a specific maybe css or javascript code that could access the database and change that... if statement? Or any other ideas?

Comment: You'll need a serverside language to generate the table. Are you using PHP?

Comment: yes...........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Konerak specified you would need a sever side language to fetch data from database and to generate that table..

Now you could do the following in case you are using php..

```
<?php
// code to connect to database
//loop in to your database entries
//fetch the row
//assign the value you want into a variable say "value"
echo "<td bgcolor=\"";
// \" used for escape sequence
if(value=="taken")
echo "blue";
else if (value=="reserved")
echo "lightgrey";
echo "\">"
//echo row contents 
echo "</td>"
//loop ends
?>
```